# How to export environment variable from .bashrc for ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu-13.04

Tried following things:

1) added "export OSTYPE=linux" in .bashrc

closed the terminal

opened the terminal

echo $OSTYPE

o/p - linux-gnu

2) added "export OSTYPE=linux" in .profile

closed the terminal

opened the terminal

echo $OSTYPE

o/p - linux-gnu

Comment: Try `source ~/.bashrc` rather than "opening/closing"? Though it sounds like OSTYPE is an environment variable, which it's unlikely you can overwrite

Comment: YES, it worked fine but when i reopened the terminal it still same "linux-gnu"

Comment: I suspect it's setting OSTYPE as an environment variable after .bashrc gets `sourced` when you open terminal, which doesn't happen when you just `source` it.

Comment: Another possibility is it's set in another bash file which gets sourced after `.bashrc`. Can you post output of `grep "OSTYPE" ~/.bash* /etc/bash.bashrc`

Comment: /home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bash_history:echo $OSTYPE 
/home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bash_history:export OSTYPE=linux 
/home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bash_history:echo $OSTYPE
/home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bash_profile:export OSTYPE=linux 
/home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bashrc:export OSTYPE=linux 
/home/PU/pratik.prajapati/.bashrc_old:export OSTYPE=linux

Comment: Can't reproduce the "bug".. I've inserted `export OSTYPE=linux` into `.bashrc` and restared the shell, ad got: 'linux'.

Comment: Interesting, tried it again and can't reproduce either. Though still not sure it's a bug regardless, depending on when bash shell variables are set.

Comment: how can i correct it ?

Comment: If you terminal starts a login shell, it will source `.bash_profile` or `.bash_login` if present instead of `.profile`, and will not source `.bashrc` at all unless one of the 3 login configuration files sources it explicitly.